# How can I update by tag and date with CVS?

Tags: cvs

I have a working sandbox and would like to update it to a specified date and tag. How can I do it? I would have thought that the following would work:

```
cvs update -r <branch> -D <old date>
```

In this case, CVS seems to ignore the date specification. If I specify just the date, then CVS drops the branch and uses HEAD instead.

Comment: I've just tried it with "current branch + 1 day ago" and "different branch + 1 day ago" and both worked as expected. Can you perhaps give a concrete example of what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

From researching on the web, it sounds like you need to do a checkout in this case and CVS is smart enough to recognize that the files need to be updated. It does not, however, recognized the branch so you have to explicitly provide it,